# Использовать Memo1 извне

Tags: c++, form, radstudio

Как можно обратиться к Memo1 с отдельной функции. Что нужно передать в параметрах?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример кода.

Comment: Нужно мне добавить строку в Memo1. Но это надо сделать из другой функции. Т.е. из события Button1Click я могу, но из другой функции не могу.

Comment: Приведите часть вашего кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть три способа. Два правильных и один не совсем, но зато рабочий.

Начнем с неправильного, но рабочего. В функции просто нужно правильно обратиться к memo - указав, к какой форме оно относиться. Это будет выглядеть скорее всего так

```
Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('line');
```

Следующий способ мне нравиться больше. Нужно эту функцию сделать методом. Поднимитесь выше по коду, в секцию private объявления формы. И добавьте туда объявление функции в одну строку

```
private
  ...
  function add_line(line:string): integer;
```

теперь нажимаем Ctrl+Shift+C и среда сгенерирует готовый метод, где можно добавить нужный код

```
function TForm1.add_line(line:string): integer;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(line);
  return Memo1.Lines.count;
end;
```

И последний способ. Он немного странный, но в нем есть своя прелесть. 
Функцию объявляем так:

```
function add_line(lines:TStrings, line:string):integer;
begin
  lines.add(line);
  return 0;
end;
```

а вызывать нужно так

```
add_line(Memo1.Lines, 'test');
```

На первый взгляд выглядит странно и плохо. Но у этого решения есть один плюс. Сама функция ничего не знает о memo. Более того, этой функции можно передать и другие объекты "со строками". Например, listBox или TStringLis.

```
add_line(ListBox1.Items, 'test');
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне надо было на C++, но у вас Delphi. Хотя первый вариант сработал отлично! ` Form3->Memo1->Lines->Add("test"); ` Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Увидел RadStudio и поехал писать:). Билдер я давно-давно уже пробовал и не ручаюсь, что напишу все правильно. Но суть от этого абсолютно не меняется.